# Running the iOS 7.0 simulator in XCode5: How to fix the window to display the standard iPhone frame

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios7, xcode5

I'm having difficulty displaying the standard iPhone frame when running the iOS 7.0 simulator in XCode 5.0.  I've tried numerous approaches to fix this, including:

1. Hooking up my laptop to a larger monitor (the screen resolution is 1920 x 1200).
2. Making sure the window is scaled to 100% ([as stated in the Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH3-SW7)).
3. Selecting each of the different iPhone devices to test it out on.
4. Adding my own custom .png iPhone image to the simulator by going to Applications > R-click on XCode > Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > Applications > R-click on iOS Simulator > Show Package Contents > Contents > Resources.

Still, all the iPhone simulators display as a window (except, quite oddly, the 3.5-inch iPhone simulator which shows up with an iPad frame):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Tel.jpg

I've never had this issue before in older versions of XCode. Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChuckKelly This question is about the frame that was removed almost 3 years ago in Xcode 5; *not* running the simulator. How you ended up on a post about a specific Xcode feature that is now irrelevant is beyond me. Stackoverflow is for constructive answers, so please respect the site and your colleagues and only write constructive responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame only appears if there is a sufficiently large resolution to display both the simulator and frame. On that display, you will only be able to have the frame if you rotate the external 1920x1200 monitor to portrait mode.

To have the frame of a retina 4" phone simulator, have your display in portrait (1200x1920) and rotate the display in OS X by 90 or 270 degrees. Have the simulator in that display. The frame will appear.

Comment: Thanks for the input Leo! I gave it a shot, and it partially worked -- the iPhone displays went from displaying a window to each displaying an iPad frame -- still not the standard iPhone frame I was hoping for though. Any other suggestions? Maybe this was an intentional change for the new Xcode?

Comment: It has been like that ever since they introduced the 4" simulator. My guess is to allow showing the frame on as lower resolution as possible. I am not aware of methods of changing the frame graphics. Why are you so bothered by it?

Comment: Ah, I see. I just liked having the iPhone simulator to record videos of my app functionality for marketing purposes. Oh, well. I'll get over it! :)  Thanks again Leo! Much appreciated.

Comment: You can record just the OS view, and then add a true iPhone frame later in post.

Comment: @Novie I just noticed that on my retina MBP, the 4" retina simulator has the full frame, of a real iPhone. I guess, this is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the update Leo! That would explain it -- I'm on a MacBook Air. I figure I'll take this as an opportunity to be creative with the iPhone frame when I do edit it in post-production!

Comment: so in my case, when I tried either retina 3.5" or 4" the emulator is shown too big for my MacBookPro 15". So as a workaround I scaled it down to 50% and it looks better. iOS Emulator --> Window --> Scale --> 50%

Answer (score 1):

That is how all of the retina based devices are displayed in the iOS simulator. It shows all of the retina based devices with no phone frame, like you have seen. All of the devices that run iOS 7 have retina displays, which results in the simulator displaying them the way they do. The simulator with the phone frame is a non-retina example using iOS 6 and prior.

Comment: This is incorrect. On a display with a sufficiently large resolution, the frame is there.

Comment: My mistake. I don't have any larger resolution screen. So from my own observations this is how it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonathan!  I wonder why the 3.5-inch iPhone has an iPad frame, though... weird.  RIP iPhone simulator :(